# Iphone application store url in application

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone application does some processing on a server, and I save the url in a core data database so that every time the application is run I can read the url value from the database.

My issue is: if this url value changes, my application will stop working.  How can I get the url value dynamically without storing it in a database so that if url is changed, my application will continue working?

Comment: I'm sure you've got a good reason to be saving this in the Core Data, only, with the little info you've divulged about your app, I'm pretty worried you're not going about this in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get get it from any server, open a [NSURLConnection class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and read the response. So basically at the beginning your app would always check with the server to make sure it has the latest URL.